# T-SQL select 1 where '{' < 'a' why does this return a result, it should be empty

Tags: t-sql

T-SQL select 1 where '{' < 'a' why does this return a result, it should be empty

The brace characters have an ASCII value greater then 'a'.  I expected an empty result just like if I did:

select 1 where 'b' < 'a'

Comment: The ASCII value and the ordering of characters are not the same thing. The *ordering* of characters is based on the collation. In a binary collation, such as `Latin1_General_BIN`, your query does not return `1`.

Comment: Is there a table that I can reference for this?

Comment: My collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, the ordering of characters isn't based on the ASCII values of the characters (`123` for `{` and `97` for `a`), but the collation.

I don't know what collation you are using, but in the collation you are using a left brace (`{`) has a *lower* value than the characters `a`. So, perhaps you are using `Latin1_General_CI_AI`:

```sql
SELECT 1 WHERE '{' < 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI;
```

If you were to be using a binary collation, such as `Latin1_General_BIN`, then you would not get a result:

```sql
SELECT 1 WHERE '{' < 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

Even the orders of letters can be different. Take the following:

```sql
SELECT 1 WHERE 'B' < 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
SELECT 1 WHERE 'B' < 'a' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

Note that the first statement does not return a result, but the latter does. This is because in `Latin1_General_CS_AS` letters are ordered alphabetically and then uppercase and lowercase, AaBbCc...YyZz. For a binary collation they are uppercase, lowercase and then alphabetically, ABC..YZabc...yz.

IF you want to see the ordering of the letters, you could do something like this for Latin based collations:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
SELECT T.I,
       V.C
FROM Tally T
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CHAR(T.I) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI))V(C) --Replace collation as needed
ORDER BY V.C;
```

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS is my collation.  Is there a URL for the codes and their corresponding characters, like http://asciitable.com?

Comment: I don't believe so, @Gurthang99 . But you could run some SQL to get the ordering yourself for Latin based collations: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CAnnRluN)